# Pronouncing Methane

Tags: pronunciation

The first “e” in *methane* is pronounced like the “e” in *metal* in the US  but it is pronounced like the “e” in *me* in the UK.

I asked a friend how this difference in pronunciation came about.  She immediately replied that the gas was discovered by an Italian in the year 1776.  Coincidentally this was the same year that the US declared its independence from the UK and that the difference in pronunciation was a deliberate act of colonial defiance.

Is there any truth in her statement or was she attempting to be humorous?

Comment: According to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=methane), the word *methane* was coined in 1867. Likely the difference is due to the difference between the pronunciations of *methyl* in the U.S. and the U.K., as the word *methane* was derived from the word *methyl*.

Comment: Etymologically, *ethane* should be pronounced like *me*, since it is derived (through several intermediaries) from the word *ether*. And *methane* should be pronounced like *metal* since it is derived (with several intermediaries) from the French word *méthylène*. However, I would be surprised if there are people who don't rhyme *methane* and *ethane*.

Comment: @PeterShor If the OED’s pronunciation variants are anything to go by, there are: _ethane_ has BrE variants with both long and short e, but _methane_ only with long e. So presumably there are some Brits out there who have unetymological vowel lengths in _both_ those words.

Comment: I find this defiance theory highly implausible.

Comment: Might it be generally true that the British use long vowels more often than Americans do?

Comment: @Michael: then explain why the British say *agile*, *fragile*, and *fertile* while Americans say *agil*, *fragil*, and *fertil*.

Comment: @PeterShor : That's exactly what I said, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the actual question here is very easy to answer (the answer is **no**, there is no truth whatsoever in her statement), I will instead comment a bit on why it *really* is that *methane* has two varying pronunciations.

Note that this is not merely a BrE vs. AmE thing—while AmE generally only has the pronunciation with the short e, BrE has both.

*Methane* is derived from *methyl* + *-ane* (used in chemical compounds). *Methyl* itself is back-formed (originally in Swedish) from *methylene*. This is ultimately based on the Ancient Greek word *μεθύ* [meˈθy] ‘sweet wine’ (cognate with English *mead* and Sanskrit *madhú-*, all from a root that just means ‘sweet’). Note that Greek ε is a *short* e.

The back-formation of *methyl* from *methylene* was based on the very similar-sounding pair of *ethyl* and *ethylene*, which was just a few years old itself when *methyl* was back-formed. *Ethyl* was formed in German, from the base of *(a)ether* + *-yl* (used in names of chemical groups).

*Ether* itself is from the Ancient Greek *αἰθήρ* [aiˈθɛːɾ] ‘upper layer of the stratosphere’, which has a diphthong /ai/. This diphthong regularly (through Latin *ae* and Old French *é*) yields a long e in English.

In other words, etymology means that we **should** have:

*Meth-* [mɛθ-] with a short e
*Eth-* [iːθ-] with a long e

But there are so many pairs between the two—*(m)ethyl*, *(m)ethylene*, *(m)ethane*, etc.—so it’s not that strange, really, that people started getting their long and short e’s mixed up a bit, particularly when you remember that the long e in *eth-* is automatically shortened in words where it loses its stress, like *ethereal*.

In AmE, this confusion has mostly meant that the long e of *eth-* has been shortened except in *ether* itself: *ethane*, *ethanol*, *ethyl*, and *ethylene* all tend to have a short e, unetymologically. The short e in *meth-* has been retained.

In BrE, the confusion is more random: *eth-* tends to have both long and short variants in many derivations, but not all (*ethanol*, for instance, always has a short e, and *ether* itself always has its etymological long e); while *meth-* has taken over the long e in some derivations, but not all (e.g., *methane* always has a long e, while *methanol* always has a short e).

Pure transatlantic chaos, in other words.

Comment: I am confused.  Are you saying that these never was a common pronunciation?

Comment: There probably was, in the very beginning, for a short while. Back when the words were only used by a tiny group of people who were writing articles back and forth in scientific journals, they probably knew which ones had short and long vowels. The words were all formed within a decade or so, in the 1830s and 1840s. I doubt any such consensus lasted very long, though, and I’d imagine the smaller amount of variation found in AmE today is the result of a later simplification of an otherwise quite random system.